# How to Convert Varchar(1) to Bit in Sql Query?

Tags: sql, bit, varchar

I want to convert a `varchar(1)` to `bit` (True or False) or (0,1).

For example if `varchar(1)` value is 'N' means it should be convert to '1' else it should be convert to '0'.

Is it possible in SQL?

Comment: N=>1 is an unusual mapping. Is that really what you're looking for? (Most people would interpret N as "No", which generally maps to a false value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case`

```
select case when your_varchar_column = 'N' 
            then 1 
            else 0 
       end as your_bool_result
from your_table
```

Depending on your SQL engine you could also use an `if` statement if available.

Comment: Thanks juergen d, it is helpful for me.